# Rename unamed column in bigquery standard-sql

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to rename the first and only column generated by the function UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,5,1)) so it can be used in a JOIN.

I've tried the solutions detailed in this article but it seems that STANDARD SQL doesn't support these kind of aliases: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/naming-unnamed-columns

Answer (score 2):

See simplified example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 10 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 12
)
SELECT id, val 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,5,1)) key
ON id = key
ORDER BY id
```

Should be self-descriptive :o)

Answer (score 0):

You can give it an alias like `as array_values` in the `select` statement and in your query reference it using the alias name.